# Questões localizadas geograficamente devem ser permitidas?

Tags: debate

Dentro das regras normais de todas as redes do Stack Exchange uma questão localizada geograficamente deve ser fechada embora não tenha mais um motivo específico para isso.

Faz sentido limitar esse tipo de questão aqui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ser "localizada geograficamente" não era a razão da existência do "too localized". O *too* era mais importante que o *localized* na definição, e uma pergunta só deveria ser fechada com essa razão caso fosse *extremamente* localizada, ou seja, caso a probabilidade de que ela pudesse ajudar *qualquer outra pessoa* fosse mínima.

Sendo assim, não vejo nenhum problema em termos questões sobre países, estados, cidades, bairros ou mesmo quarteirões específicos aqui. Se a pergunta for útil para alguém além do "perguntador"<sup>1</sup>, por mim é uma pergunta válida.

<sup>(1) Precisamos achar um bom termo em pt para "asker" ou "OP"...</sup>

Comment: Precisamos achar bons termos p/ muitas coisas :) Acho que o SO era mais fácil :D

Comment: Concordo. O stackoverflow.com possui questões válidas  que se aplicam apenas a um país, como http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517026/how-can-i-validate-us-social-security-number

Comment: @rodrigorgs [Outro exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)

Answer (score 3):

Acho que aqui fica mais fácil administrar esse tipo de questão pelo menos quando se trata de países. Portanto acho que deveria ser válido.

O ideal seria adicionar uma tag à questão indicando que ela é válida para um país específico.